# Update the first and last 2 charactors with year and month

Tags: sql, sql-update, getdate

I have a value that I need to change the first characters with the year and the last 2 characters with the month. The AttributeValue field value is 17WEBD01. I need to update the 17 with the current years last two digits and I need to update the 01 with the current month of 02.

I tried this statement and I get an error on the Left statement

```
UPDATE [EC_StoreAttributes]

   SET Left(AttributeValue, 2) = SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101),2), 
       Right(AttributeValue, 2) = SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101),2)

WHERE AttributeType = 'ECSRCCODE' and StoreRecordId = '1'
```

Comment: what is column name you are trying to update, and why `left`, `right` functions used for column names

Comment: whats the exact error you get?

Why are you using the Date, I would just do string manipulation directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update one column in one go by Casting and combining strings. They are `integer` outputs, so you have to cast them to `varchar (2)`. First part of string replacing year (first 2 values) and `replace` used again to replace right part of string

```
UPDATE [EC_StoreAttributes]
SET AttributeValue = REPLACE(CAST((
                SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), 2)
                ) AS VARCHAR(2)) + REPLACE(AttributeValue, left(AttributeValue, 2), ''), RIGHT(CAST((
                    SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), 2)
                    ) AS VARCHAR(2)) + REPLACE(AttributeValue, left(AttributeValue, 2), ''), 2), '') + REPLACE(RIGHT(CAST((
                    SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), 2)
                    ) AS VARCHAR(2)) + REPLACE(AttributeValue, left(AttributeValue, 2), ''), 2), RIGHT(attributevalue, 2), CAST((
                SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), 2)
                ) AS VARCHAR(2)))
        WHERE AttributeType = 'ECSRCCODE'
         AND StoreRecordId = '1'
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the , after VARCHAR(2)   I also need to keep the value in the middle and only change the year in front and the month in the back should look like this 18webd02

Comment: you can add your value column in the middle , i have removed , after first string, it should execute now.

Comment: This added the year and month to the value.   I need the year and month replaced with the current ones. 
    UPDATE [EC_StoreAttributes] 
    SET AttributeValue = 
    CAST((SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), 2)) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 
    AttributeValue +
    CAST((SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), 2)) AS VARCHAR(2))
    WHERE AttributeType = 'ECSRCCODE'
     AND StoreRecordId = '1'

Comment: Here is what the results were:  1817WEBD0102

Comment: @user1667160              I guess i have given u the same script, are u happy that its working now ?

Comment: how do I replace the old year and month code with the current year and month code so that 17webd01 will get replaced with 18webd02.   currently it is adding the year and month code to the value.

Comment: @user1667160       Can you please add sample data and required out put, ex: atleast 4-5 rows of data for AttributeValue and expected output in a different column

Comment: Import: 17webd01,  17sweb01, 17rcrs01, 17rcre01 

Output should look like 18webd02, 18sweb02, 18rcrs02, 18rcre02.

Comment: @user1667160 updated for required output, please check and let me know